how to make conversationalretrievalchain to include metadata in the prompt using langchain with chromadb to make the LLM aware of metadata?
im trying to do a bot that answer questions from a chromadb , i have stored multiple pdf files with metadata like the filename and candidate name , my problem is when i use conversational retrieval chain the LLM model just receive page_content without the metadata , i want the LLM model to be aware of the page_content with its metadata like filename and candidate name
here is my code
conversation_chain=ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(llm,vectorstore,document_content_description,metadata_field_info),
       
        memory=memory,
        verbose=True,
       
        
    )

and here is my attribute info
metadata_field_info = [
    AttributeInfo(
        name="filename",
        description="The name of the resumee",
        type="string",

        
    ),
    AttributeInfo(
        name="candidatename",
        description="the name of the candidate",
        type="string"
    )

]


i tried this return_source_documents=True and it didnt work

I did fix this issue by including document_prompt
    document_combine_prompt = PromptTemplate(
     input_variables=["candidatename","page_content"],
     template= """
        page_content: {page_content}
        candidatename:{candidatename}
        """
)
    conversation_chain=ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(llm,vectorstore,document_content_description,metadata_field_info,verbose=True),
        
        memory=memory,
        verbose=True,
        return_source_documents=True,
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": custom_prompt,
                                   "document_prompt":document_combine_prompt
                                   }
    )

